# Covering abelian varieties over finite fields with the product of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties

> **Question.** Given an $n$-dimensional abelian variety $X$ over a finite field, is it possible to find smooth projective curves
> $C_1,\ldots, C_n$ such that there exists a finite regular map
> $C_1\times \ldots \times C_n\rightarrow X$?

Edit: I'd like a reference for the statement in comments: If we take $C_i$ a smooth complete intersection curve then their product should cover the abelian variety.

I was thinking maybe using the [space filling curve](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Enmk/spacefill.pdf), we have a sequence of space-filling curves that cover all rational points, picking $n$ of them we can define a map from their product to $X$, by first mapping the product to the product of $n$-copies of $X$ and then taking the sum of it. This gives a regular map from product of $n$ curves to $X$ which is surjective let's say on $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ points, which we can take $m$ to be arbitrarily large. The only problem is that one needs to verify that image of this map is $n$-dimensional. Although I don't know how to prove it, it seems intuitively obvious.

Comment: $n$-dimensional varieties and ${\Bbb F}_{p^n}$ -points, where we can take $n$ to be arbitrarily large?

Comment: Sorry I'll fix it.

Comment: There's no need to take it to be surjective on $\mathbb F_{p^m}$-points. Any smooth complete intersection curve will do.

Comment: @WillSawin is there any proof of this fact in the literature?

Comment: This is one of the facts that is surely in the literature but I would never know where to find in the literature.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.11015.pdf